# JQuery/Grails marking multiple options/values as selected in multiple select box

Tags: javascript, jquery, grails, select

I have this multiple select:

```
        <select type="text" name="specialTypeInd" id="specialTypeInd" multiple>
          <option value="">None</option>
          <option value="I">International</option>
          <option value="M">Minority</option>
          <option value="S">Study Abroad</option>
        </select>
```

Previously I was choosing just a single select option based off of a single value:

```
document.getElementById('specialTypeInd').value = hashNames[item][13]
```

where hashNames[item][13] = a single value such as I and the select was just a single select box.

Now I need it as a multiple select but I still need to accomplish marking them as selected by doing:

```
document.getElementById('specialTypeInd').value = hashNames[item][13]
```

but now where hashNames[item][13] can look like just a single value such as I or it could be multiple values such as I,S.

Any help on how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up figuring out a solution shown below:

```
$.each(hashNames[item][13].split(","), function(i,e){
        $("#specialTypeInd option[value='" + e + "']").prop("selected", true);
});
```